# Can you use email addresses instead of user names in a security group?

Tags: lotus-notes

I haven't been able to get this to work and don't think it will but thought I'd ask just in case.

- I have a security Group.  Instead of putting user names in the Members field, I put email addresses.
- I added the email addresses to the users' 'user name' field in their Domino Directory user document.
- I added the security group to a database's ACL then assigned it a role.
- I create a form which displays a user's role and the role does not show up.
- If I put the user's name in the security group Members fields, the role does show up.

Has anyone done this before?

thanks,
clem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to open a PMR on the issue and IBM confirmed that you CAN'T do this.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that you can't do this.